# How to show that a set of vectors do not span $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show that these vectors $\{(-1, -2, -1), (-1,-5,-1), (-1,-1,-1)\}$ do not span in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by giving a vector not in there span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that all the vectors have the same first and last components. Therefore any linear combination will also have the same first and last components. So choose a vector with different ones, like $(1,0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of more general ways you can use in other cases where an orthogonal vector can't be found immediately (a la Chappers' answer):

Method You Can Use in $\Bbb R^n$ for Any $n$:

1. Verify your vectors are linearly dependent.  You can do so using Gauss-Jordan elimination.
2. If they are not linearly independent, throw out any vectors that are a linear combination of the others.  NOTE: Obviously none of the three vectors in this case are multiples of the others so the maximum you will need to throw out is $1$ vector.
3. Construct a matrix with the remaining vectors as rows.
4. Solve the homogeneous system to obtain the set of vectors that is orthogonal to your set.

Method You Can Use Because Your Vectors Happen to Be in $\Bbb R^3$ Where the Cross Product Is Defined:

1. To verify your vectors are linearly dependent you could take the triple scalar product.  If it is zero, the vectors are linearly dependent.
2. Same as above.
3. Take the cross product of the two remaining vectors to obtain a vector orthogonal to your set.